# VB Getting DataGridView to stay on same cell if validation (CellEndEdit fails

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi I am very new to programming. Managed to make a helpful program last month and am now onto slightly bigger things- DataGridviews are hurting my head. My Datagridview is not bound to a Database. In short i have two DataGridviews on two different forms- one is essentially a Dictionary- and the other is a Data Entry Sheet (a bit like excel). The DataEntry Datagrid Cross references the Dictionary Datagrid. I have got this working however what i need to do is - if the data cell in the data entry sheet is not in the dictionary after editing then it will not go to another cell (IE. stuck in that cell until a correct dictionary value is added. I can currently make it say msgbox"not in dictionary" however my code for not allowing moving out of the cell is not working-

Here is the code

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit


    Dim Row As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim temp As Integer = 0

    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To FormGeoDicLith.DataGridViewDicLith.RowCount - 1

'this code references a column in the datagrid dictionary to see if the correct value has been added to the data entry datagrid

            If DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(2).Value = FormGeoDicLith.DataGridViewDicLith.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Then
                MsgBox("Item found")
                temp = 1
            End If
        Next

        If temp = 0 Then

'this is the problem area
            DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(2).Selected = True

            MsgBox("Code Not In Dictionary")

            Exit Sub

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(2).Selected = True although it looks like it selects the cell- then it just un-selects and I am not stuck in the cell like i want to be until a correct dictionary item is entered. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd be investigating what events are being called after CellEndEdit. One of them may be preventing your desired behavior.

Comment: Agreed but the events are not being called by me- they are being called by the DatagridView default behaviour

Comment: That's true, but you can always throw in their event handling methods and throw in a println and see which ones are raised as the dgv operates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataGridView.CellValidating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that occurs when a cell loses input focus, enabling content validation.

For example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

    If e.FormattedValue < 0 Or e.FormattedValue > 20 Then
        MsgBox("Please specify a valid value between 0 and 20.")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

You can validate only particular column filtering by `e.ColumnIndex`.

Comment: The Cell validating event plays havoc with my code- I tried it before "endedit".

Comment: End edit is working for everything except the ability for it to not allow exiting of the cell- i played around with key chars-and key downs (my original idea was to validate on the go and create automatic cell moving after a correct entry- but this too was having all sorts of unintended consequences.

Comment: If you have problem with CellValidating during a particular process (i.e.: when you populate your DataGridView for the first time) try using AddHandler and RemoveHandler to dinamically add/remove this event (link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I ended up going with a Telerik Radgrid and using the cell validating event. It caused a lot less dramas.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bit of progress with-

DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(2)

```
            MsgBox("Code Not In Dictionary")

            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
```

the begin edit function does pull me back to the cell although the next cell is selected then the it is pulled back to the correct cell and put in edit mode. It takes 2 presses of the enter key instead of one after Msgbox and seems to fail if i continually put in a wrong value/ends up not selecting the cell for some reason.

Comment: Actually- It goes back to the Cell and then you think you are editing the cell but then it strangely decides to put the value in the cell next to it (very strange)

Comment: I ended up giving up for the stock DatagridView and moved towards a Telerik Radgrid. I have managed to get rid of all of the above mentioned problems by doing this (with some drama but much less than with the Datagridview).